# Why is there an equal sign in the return of this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, return

This is a section of sample code in MDN telling about async/await:

```js
async function hello() {
  return greeting = await Promise.resolve("Hello");
};

hello().then(alert);
```

What is `return *** = ***;`?

Comment: In this example, completely superfluous. same as `return await Promise....`

Comment: @Jamiec — It assigns the result of awaiting the promise to the `greeting` variable (which isn't declared here but is presumably in a scope outside the hello function) so neither part of that expression is superfluous (although it is probably a bad way to solve whatever problem is being solved)

Comment: @Quentin True, but implied by my comment was _in the code shown here_ it is superfluous.

Comment: That's the [complete example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#the_await_keyword) - with _"Of course, the above example is not very useful, although it does serve to illustrate the syntax."_ below it. The `greeting = ...` part doesn't make any sense... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about `=` here.

This just says:

1. Evaluate the expression on the right hand side
2. Return the result

So it evaluates `greeting = await Promise.resolve("Hello");` exactly as if `return` wasn't involved, then it returns the result of that expression (which is the same as the value that was just assigned to `greeting`).

```js
let foo = "123";

function hello() {
    return foo = "abc";
}

const bar = hello();

console.log({foo, bar});
```

Comment: Now that it has been "return", what is the point of assigning it again?

Comment: @红日初升 —  There isn't enough context provided in the question to tell.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it is very simple to test via browser console.

`function test(v) { let t; return t = v;}  test(5);`

You will see that it returns the assigned value.

*PS.
It is very important to learn to use the console, it is a gift actually! A real time extremelly simple ''compiler'' per se, that most languages do have the luxury of.
Try to find ways to work things out before reach out for help, it will be appreciated, plus it will be great for your skills.*